# How to listen to a socket.io event on a route in order to redirect to another route in express?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, express-router

I am trying to replicate the web whatsapp QRCode authentication for my Final Year Project which is an Online Medical Management System. In this system long story short, the doctor should be able to view the patients prescriptions only if the patient allows him and that permission should be given when he scans the QRcode generated by the doctors profile from his app which sends an authStatus on a socket event which will enable the server to redirect to the patients record route.

The server socket setup is given as follows:

```
router.get('/patientinfoqrcode',redirectRoutes.redirectLoginDoctor,function(req,res){
    let usernameQR = req.query.usernameQR
    let message='';
    io.on("connection",function(socket){
        console.log("The user has been connected")

        io.on("disconnect",function(){
            console.log("The user has been disconnected")
        })

        socket.on("Auth",function(data){
            if(data.authStatus=='authorized'){
                res.redirect(`/dashboard?usernamePatient=${usernameQR}`)
            }
        });

    })

    res.render('doctor/patientinfoqrcode',{usernameQR})
});
```

The nativescript app setup is given below:

```
const socketio = SocketIO.connect('https://secret-falls-76814.herokuapp.com/patientinfoqrcode'
    , options);

export function scanQR(args) {
    barcodescanner.scan({
    formats: "QR_CODE",   // Pass in of you want to restrict scanning to certain type
    message: "Use the volume buttons for extra light", // Android only, default is 'Place a barcode inside the viewfinder rectangle to scan it.'
    showFlipCameraButton: true,   // default false
    preferFrontCamera: false,     // default false
    showTorchButton: true,        // default false
    beepOnScan: true,             // Play or Suppress beep on scan (default true)
    torchOn: false,               // launch with the flashlight on (default false)
    closeCallback: function () { console.log("Scanner closed"); }, // invoked when the scanner was closed (success or abort)
    resultDisplayDuration: 500,   // Android only, default 1500 (ms), set to 0 to disable echoing the scanned text
    orientation: "landscape",     // Android only, optionally lock the orientation to either "portrait" or "landscape"
    openSettingsIfPermissionWasPreviouslyDenied: true // On iOS you can send the user to the settings app if access was previously denied
  }).then(
      function(result) {
        console.log("Scan format: " + result.format);
        console.log("Scan text:   " + result.text);
        const button = args.object;
        button.text = result.text;
            socketio.emit('Auth',{
                authStatus:'authorized'
            });

      },
      function(error) {
        console.log("No scan: " + error);
      }
  );
}
```

And it isnt working like its supposed to. The only problem I think there is that the socket.io listening to the event is inside the /patientinfoqrcode route and that route performs all the functions inside it the moment it loads. Then even if some thing happens within the body of the router.get() nothing will happen because it has already rendered the document. The server whole project is uploaded on heroku

Comment: You don't listen to socket.io messages in a route handler.  That's a recipe for disaster because those listeners apply to ALL incoming connections no matter what route they came from and they never get removed either.  You listen to socket.io messages at the top level.  If you want, your client can uniquely identify their connection from a specific page by either connecting to a specific namespace or by sending a message from that page that you can act on.

Comment: @jfriend00 How can i redirect thou if I dont include the listener inside a route handler? I would have declared it in the top if i didnt have to do anything related to routes

Comment: If you want to redirect from a socket.io message, you send back a message and have the Javascript inside the page get the new location from that message and set `window.location` to cause the redirect.  You can't redirect inside a socket.io message.  Your design thinking is not taking into account how the client/server/socket.io flow actually works.

Comment: This about this another way.  In your route handler, you get a request for a page.  You send that page with `res.render()`.  Then the browser parses that page and runs the Javascript in it, causing a socket.io connection to be made.  The original request sent to the server is now completely DONE.  You can't redirect that.  It has already happened and sent a response and is done.

Comment: @jfriend00 oh nice. Thanks man. Never really thought like that. Guess PHP has ruined me lmao. Should have started with nodejs

Comment: Yeah, PHP has a complete different model.  Here you have ONE server instance for all page requests.